# Java JDBC point cursor to previous resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I have to point cursor position back to the previous one when I break the while loop.

Below is the my while loop code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    docId = rs.getString("DOCID");
    System.out.println("In : extractData(1st):docId"+docId);
    // if previous id is not match with the current id then exitfrom while loop.
    if(previousDocId != null && !previousDocId.equals(docId)){
        //move cruser back.
        break;
    }
    thisIsAStringArray[0] = firstDocId;
    String name1 = rs.getString("field_name");
    System.out.println("field Name:"+name1);
    if("address".equals(name1) && 1 == rs.getInt("field_type")){
        thisIsAStringArray[1] = rs.getString("field_string");
    }
    // 
    previousDocId = docId;
}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

When you get your `ResultSet` you have to set property `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` or `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` for it to make it scrollable

Assume you got that `ResultSet` from `Statement`:

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement(
   ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE // scrollable    
);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(your query);
```

And use `rs.previous()` to move backward.

Comment: In spring how can I mention this?

Comment: What do you mean? You showing the code using JDBC and ask for spring workaround?

Comment: I am using spring batch for my data base processing as below: <bean id="databaseItemReader"
  class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="sql"
   value="select * from uddocument where udd.docid IN (1,405183) AND uff.field_name IN ('address','contractNb','city') " />
  <property name="rowMapper">
   <bean class="com.migration.springbatch.UDocumentResultRowMapper" />
  </property>
  <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false"/>
 </bean>

Comment: If you use `ResultSet` as you mentioned in your question, then process as my answer. If you working want solution for spring please post another question with detail code you're working now